# Devise/OmniAuth: different logic for for registration and login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

The default devise authorization path (i.e. user_omniauth_authorize_path mentioned [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)) appears to be designed to work for both OmniAuth registration and login. By the time auth is received in the OmniauthCallbacksController, your rails app typically uses the auth information to create a new user or update an existing user regardless of whether the user intended to login or register with a service (i.e. Facebook).

My stakeholders have requested different behavior for auth and login. If a user clicks "Register with Facebook" and there's no account with their Facebook email, they want to go ahead and create an account with that email. However, if a user clicks "Login with Facebook" and there's no account with their Facebook email, they want to present the user with an error message explaining "The Facebook account you are using does not match an account in our records. Please sign in using your barre3 email and password"

The place for this logic seems to be in the OmniauthCallbacksController's Facebook method. What's the cleanest way to pass the user's intent ('login' or 'register') into this callback method?

Answer (score 6):

You can get back parameters from the authorization to indicate the user's intent by adding some parameters on the authorization URL.

For example:

```
- if devise_mapping.omniauthable?
  - resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider|
    = link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider, {intent: :sign_in})
```

(This creates a URL like: http://whatevs.dev/users/auth/facebook?intent=sign_in)

Then, in the callbacks controller (whatever you name it):

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    if env["omniauth.params"]["intent"] == "sign_in"
      # Don't create a new identity
    else
      # Normal flow, such as:
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> If a user clicks "Register with Facebook" and there's no account with their Facebook email, they want to go ahead and create an account with that email

This assumption is not valid since Facebook can be created with just a phone number. Even user has an email, extra permission is required to get the user email from Facebook. 
Your application should validate facebook_uid returned by Facebook API instead of email.

> What's the cleanest way to pass the user's intent ('login' or 'register') into this callback method?

For OmniAuth there is no difference between the 'login' or 'register'. All it does is try to authenticate the user with the provided Facebook token. 
One clean way to differentiate is to separate on the controller level. If user tries to login in, call SessionsController#create, if user tries to sign up, call UsersController#create.

Comment: Is there a way to identify the creation of the user (first login) and redirect them to a welcome page? Using only Omniauth.

Answer (score 0):

I have also researched too much for the answer but didn't get any satisfactory answer so I took a step forward and create functionality to work as required. @Jason answer helps me to reach here.

**views/users/sessions/new.html.erb**

```
<% if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <% resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider, {intent: :sign_in}) do %>
      <i class="fa fa-<%= provider.to_s.split('_')[0] %>"></i>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**views/users/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<% if devise_mapping.omniauthable? %>
  <% resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
    <%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider, {intent: :sign_up}) do %>
      <i class="fa fa-<%= provider.to_s.split('_')[0] %>"></i>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        if request.env["omniauth.params"]["intent"] == "sign_up"
          @user = User.from_omniauth_sign_up(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        elsif request.env["omniauth.params"]["intent"] == "sign_in"
          @user = User.from_omniauth_sign_in(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        end
        
        if @user.present?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          flash[:errors] = {:email => "is not registered with us."}
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end

  [:google_oauth2, :facebook, :linkedin].each do |provider|
    provides_callback_for provider
  end

end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth_sign_up(auth)
  # check if email address obtained from auth server is in User table
  user = User.where(email: auth[:info][:email]).first
  if user.present?
    user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
    user.last_name  = auth.info.last_name
    user.image      = auth.info.image
    user.provider   = auth.provider
    user.uid        = auth.uid
    user.save   
  else
    user            = User.new(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    user.email      = auth.info.email
    user.username   = "#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}"
    user.password   = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
    user.last_name  = auth.info.last_name
    user.image      = auth.info.image
    user.status_id  = 2
    user.skip_mobile_validation = true
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save
  end
  user
end

def self.from_omniauth_sign_in(auth)
  if user = User.where(email: auth[:info][:email]).first
    user
  end
end
```